# 1000Mbps switch worthwhile for LAN transfer when I have a 10/100Mbps router?

Tags: lan, switch

I need to lan transfer files between two computers,

Right now I have 2 computers in my room,

1 connected through 10/100Mbps router with a 5e cable

1 connected through wifi

Problem, I need more speed!

If I connect the two computers and the router to a 1000Mbps switch (all 5e cables) will the computer transfer between them at 1000Mbps?

(The router is the only thing in another room)

PS

I am using TeamViewer to transfer the files (accept exclusively lan configured)

Comment: Basically I want to know if it's worthwhile to spend $10 more, I see 100Mbits are $10, 1000Mbits $20

Comment: "Need more speed" between what? If between the internet and yourself, obviously, a 1Gig router won't help, and if directly between two computers on the same local network, it will help

Comment: Marcus, first line "I need to lan transfer files between two computers"

Comment: I read that, but there are people that do things like local network -> internet-> relay -> internet -> local network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a 10/100/1000 switch will run each port at its max speed. Plugging a 100Mbps device into a gigabit switch will NOT drop the whole switch down to 100Mbps. Your two gigabit clients will get gigabit speed transfers.

Spend the extra $10. No-brainer. 100Mbps gear has been obsolete since the late 1990's.

Comment: seriously, if you find a local retail that still has 100 Mbit switches... they've made some bad stock choice, or sales of network equipment has been *really* slow over the last 15 years

Comment: Thanks Spiff, I realize it's a noob question but it's the first switch I buy (better safe than sorry).

Comment: *"100Mbps gear has been obsolete since the late 1990's."* -- Rubbish!.  Integrated Gigabit ports on motherboards were not common until about 2005-ish.  The industrial side of the networking market (rather than the PC side which you  probably only think of)  has been very slow to adopt Gigabit speed. A lot of embedded network devices simply do not need the extra speed and cost.

Comment: @sawdust GbE was built into Power Macs in 1999 and was even standard on PowerBooks by 2001. I didn't realize the WinTel market had lagged that far behind.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, for the extra $10, it's worth it, but there are caveats, depending on how your network is set up:

Any traffic which goes through the router will still be limited to 100Mbps.
Any traffic over the switch will be capable of 1Gbps.

You haven't specified which Wi-Fi standard you're using, but if that traffic moves through the router (say, you have a wireless access point connected to the router) your speed will be limited to that of the router. You could, however, connect the WAP to the switch.

Comment: I have 1 cable in my room now, I will use another lan cable instead of the wifi on the second computer once the switch arrives.
Thanks for your time, upvoted.

Comment: I don't have enough repo to upvote sorry

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's absolutely, technically, correct.
If you're going to downvote, you should at least raise your head and provide a reason why.

Comment: @user682501 That should work, giving you gigabit speeds between the two machines.